# SettingWithCopyWarning using pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to figure out why the below function is returning the dreaded `SettingWithCopyWarning`...
Here is my function that intends to modify the dataframe `df` by reference.

```
def remove_outliers_by_group(df, cols):
    """
    Removes outliers based on median and median deviation computed using cols
    :param df: The dataframe reference
    :param cols: The columns to compute the median and median dev of
    :return:
    """
    flattened = df[cols].as_matrix().reshape(-1, )
    median = np.nanmedian(flattened)
    median_dev = np.nanmedian(np.abs(flattened) - median)
    for col in cols:
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.nan if get_absolute_median_z_score(x, median, median_dev) >= 2 else x)
```

And the offending line is `df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.nan if get_absolute_median_z_score(x, median, median_dev) >= 2 else x)` as per this error:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
>   using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.nan if
>   get_absolute_median_z_score(x, median, median_dev) >= 2 else x)

What I don't understand is that I see this pattern all over the place, using something like `df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ...)`, so I can't imagine *all* of them are doing it wrong.

Am I doing it wrong? What is the best way to do this? I want to modify the *original* dataframe.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not due to the apply method but the fact that you reassign a column of your dataframe.

You can use `copy()`or simply disable the warning.

Comment: So am I modifying the original dataframe in that line? That is what I want. Or am I creating a new dataframe and not modifying the passed `df` (I don't want this)

Comment: In fact, you are modifying the original dataframe, i give you more insight in an answer.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is due to the reassignement and not the fact that you use `apply`.

`SettingWithCopyWarning` is a warning that chained-indexing has been detected in an assignment. It does not necessarily mean anything has gone wrong.

To avoid, the warning, as adviced use .loc like this

df.loc[:, col] = df[col].apply(...)

Comment: My knowledge ends here, maybe read the docs about copy in pandas. In case, you want to disable the warning you can use `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`

Comment: @coolboyjules Sometimes you can get the warning even on a line that uses `loc` (as here) because the DataFrame you are working with already (`df`) is already ambiguously a copy or view before it goes into your function, so the line you'd need to change would be in the code above somewhere (usually adding a `.copy()` on some other operation).  It's annoying, but there it is.

Comment: This answer didn't solve my issue, instead, I found another answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60885847/8046546), which resolves the error by adding .reset_index(drop=True) before to the dataframe

Answer (score 21):

Make sure that `df` is a copy of another data frame. In that case, you should write your code like

`df = df_test.copy()`

This makes sure `df` is a copy and not a view.

Learn more about this warning from the below link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4R4WsDJ-KVc

Comment: Thanks, that is actually right, I solved my warning with a copy. In my case I had:
    `df = df_original['col1', 'col2']`  here add `.copy()`.
Then this will not generate warning anymore:
    `df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x)`